# Problem with youtube embed in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios

I inserted a youtube embed code (the iframe code) in a UIWebView on iPhone and since i upgraded to iOS 4.3.4 it will not play those videos anymore.

It shows fine in the uiwebview but when tapping the play button it goes blank.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

(I could use the old youtube embed code but it really stirs my display when it is returning)

best regards,
broch

Edit (July 30th 2011): It is working again! Really great. Thanks to the guys at YouTube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link, it looks like its a youtube issue and not us! Engineers are working on it.

http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/394c41dda8b4745a

Greg

Comment: Hmm... strange that we are having no problems on an iPod touch running 4.2.1. Only our devices running 4.3.x have the issue, hence why I originally thought this was something Apple had broken, rather than YouTube.

Comment: I was before using iOS 4.3.3 which worked fine. Then got 4.3.4 and later again 4.3.5 and still it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this issue exists in iOS 4.3.5 as well (tested on an iPhone 4 and iPad 2). We've found that YouTube's  embed method no longer works in a UIWebView. The video will usually play but you will only hear the audio.

Falling back to YouTube's old Flash embed code **will** solve the problem, however it is indeed slower this way. But at least it works.

In the app I'm working on, we retrieve JSON encoded data from a web server. We've simply made it so this data includes the YouTube embed code, which we can change back to the iframe at any time. That way we don't have to keep updating our app every time Apple breaks some functionality, instead we just update our JSON script which only takes a second. Hopefully you can implement some workaround similar to this, or perhaps just go with the old embed code for now until Apple or YouTube addresses the bug.

Comment: I'm showing a navigation controller modally and in the navigations 4th level it pushes another modalviewcontroller with the UIWebView. And if I in this webview uses the old embed code it plays the video alright but when returning to my app again the modalview and the navigationcontroller is dismissed showing my menu which doesn't work anymore. This is really unexpected behaviour and with the Iframe embed it worked just fine, returning to the UIWebView (before ofcourse). Do you know any reason for this behaviour of the old embed code?

Comment: Can you share about the old Flash embed code ? My application worked before, but after upgrading to iOS 5, embedded HTML in WebView does not work any more